# Unable to unmount React Component

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am trying to unmounted the react component when there is an entity change, for that I am using `rerenderSearchPanel` function in my angularJS project and then trying to mount it with `initializeSearchPanel` function.

Inside `rerenderSearchPanel` I have following code

```
searchElement && ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(searchElement);
```

but after executing this line still the component exist its structure.

```
function rerenderSearchPanel(selectedEntity, savedChips) {
        var searchElement = document.getElementById("searchPanel");
        searchElement && ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(searchElement);
        $scope.initializeSearchPanel(selectedEntity, savedChips);
    }

$scope.initializeSearchPanel = function (selectedEntity, savedChips) {

        var searchElement = document.getElementById("searchPanel");
        var searchDataSource = {
            method: "GET",
            catalogAPI: $scope.metaRestUrl + "specifications? 
                   q=specName;EQUALS;EntityAttribute&q=subType;EQUALS;English",
            searchAPI: $rootScope.smRestUrl + "graphSearch?limit=100&page=1",
            selectedEntity: (selectedEntity ? selectedEntity : 
                             $scope.currentEntity),
        };

        requestConfig.headers['TransformationEnabled'] = true;
        searchDataSource.headers = requestConfig.headers

        var options = {
            searchProps: {
                id: "searchInput1",
                placeHolder: "Search",
                editable: true,
            },
            chips: savedChips,
            onTokenChange: $scope.search,
            dataSource: searchDataSource
        }

        var search = React.createElement(SearchComponent, options);
        searchElement && ReactDOM.render(search, searchElement);
    }
```

But `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` is not unmounting.

Comment: try componentwillunmount

Comment: not resolved yet, any one please suggest, your suggestion will be highly approciated.